# Select Option with Previous and next by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, html-select

I have bug when I click next or prev button. Here is my HTML

```js
$("#nextPage").click(function() {
  $('#pagination option:selected').next().attr('selected', 'selected');
  console.log("hahaha next");
})

$("#prevPage").click(function() {
  $('#pagination option:selected').prev().attr('selected', 'selected');
  console.log("prev");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="prev" id="prevPage">
<select id="pagination">
     <option value="1" selected>1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
<input type="button" value="next" id="nextPage">
```

[Here is my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/r18qgvp8/3/)

Thank you

Comment: Some details on what this 'bug' is would be good here.

Comment: Check this:  https://jsfiddle.net/r18qgvp8/4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `prop` instead of `attr` and its work perfect.

```js
$("#nextPage").click(function() {
  $('#pagination option:selected').next().prop('selected', 'selected');
  console.log("hahaha next");
})

$("#prevPage").click(function() {
  $('#pagination option:selected').prev().prop('selected', 'selected');
  console.log("prev");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="prev" id="prevPage">
<select id="pagination">
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="next" id="nextPage">
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `.prop` instead of `.attr` as `.attr` will just add an extra attribute to each option whilst `.prop` will actually change the selected item

```js
$("#nextPage").click(function() {
  $('#pagination option:selected').next().prop('selected', true);
  console.log("hahaha next");
})

$("#prevPage").click(function() {
  $('#pagination option:selected').prev().prop('selected', true);
  console.log("prev");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="prev" id="prevPage">
<select id="pagination">
     <option value="1" selected>1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
<input type="button" value="next" id="nextPage">
```